# Create a dictionary out of a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For example, lets say we have a .txt file named letters which contains,

```
a
b
b
c
d
d
d
d
```

How would I go about creating a dictionary in which the keys are the individual letters found in the file and the values are the number of times each letter appears? For example, a would be a key and the corresponding value would be 1, while b is also a key and its value is 2.

We just started learning opening files and creating dictionaries so I would assume I would start with something like,

```
file = open('letters.txt', 'rt')
```

I am not quite sure if the rt part is right, but then we would have to search 'file' so,

```
for letter in file:
```

But I'm not quite sure how to search for letters, make them keys, and then add the number of times the letter occurs to the value in a dictionary. Any advice?

Comment: one thing to start with: try printing out variables at various stages, or call `type` or `help` on them for additional information.  if you know that `for X in file:` does something just check what `X` is, I'm sure you can deduce what you need to do by experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a convenient extension to `dict` in the `collections` module called `Counter` that does exactly what you are looking for:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> with open('letters.txt') as f:
...     c = Counter(map(str.strip, f))
>>> c
Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 4})
```

If you really want it as a `dict`:

```
>>> dict(c)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: `Counter` is already a `dict` (I.E. `isinstance(c,dict) -> True`) so converting it is only relevant for printing purposes.

Comment: While yes `Counter` is a `dict` it does have different behaviour `c['e']` returns `0`, whereas `dict(c)['e']` is a `KeyError`. So I don't quite agree it is just for display, it may depend on the behaviour expectations.

Answer (score 1):

If it were a practical problem, you should probably have done something like:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter([ln.strip() for ln in open('letters.txt')])
```

or even

```
counts = Counter(open('letters.txt').read())
```

(this will also count newline characters).

As you are apparently doing a learning exercise, you are probably looking for something like:

```
counts = dict()
for line in open('letters.txt'):
    letter = line[0]
    counts[letter] = counts.get(letter, 0) + 1
```